# How to constrain VF page to fit within width of browser without horizontal scrollbar

Tags: visualforce, html

I am trying to create a VF page that captures the records of different objects, currently the VF gets a scroll bar when rendered, i want users access entire page without having to scroll horizontally(I believe this is a common requirement).

How can i achieve using native visualforce styling/components, without using frameworks such as bootstrap etc.

My sample VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="ObjA__c"
        extensions="ObjA_Package_Ext" sidebar="false" >
        <style>
            .textarea-field {
                width: 75%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                height: 25px;
            }
            .input-field {
                width: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <apex:form id="frm">
            <apex:pageBlock Title="Title 1" rendered="true" >
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4" title="Section1 Title" >
                    <apex:inputField id="a" value="{!ObjA__c.textField1}"  required="true" styleClass="input-field"/> 
                    <apex:inputField id="a" value="{!ObjA__c.textField2}"  required="true" styleClass="input-field"/>
                    <apex:inputField id="a" value="{!ObjA__c.textField3}"  required="true" styleClass="input-field"/> 
                    <apex:inputField id="a" value="{!ObjA__c.textField4}"  required="true" styleClass="input-field"/>
                    <apex:inputField id="a" value="{!ObjA__c.textField5}"  required="true" styleClass="textarea-field"/> 
                    <apex:inputField id="a" value="{!ObjA__c.textField6}"  required="true" styleClass="textarea-field"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:outputPanel id="opId"`enter code here` > <!-- id is used for creating rows dynamically -->
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section2 Title"> 
                    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!ObjB__c}" >
                        <apex:column headerValue="Header 1">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ObjB__c.textField1}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Header 2">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ObjB__c.textField2}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Header 3">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ObjB__c.textField3}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Header 4">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ObjB__c.textField4}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Header 5">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ObjB__c.textField5}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Header 6">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ObjB__c.textField6}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Header 7">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ObjB__c.textField7}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Header 8">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!ObjB__c.textField8}"/>
                        </apex:column>                  
                    </apex:pageblockTable>                    
                </apex:pageblockSection>            
                </apex:outputPanel>  

            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `<apex:form>` inside `<body></body>` tag and add CSS

```
body{
width:100%;
overflow-x:hidden; 
}
```